# Is Yosemite really required for uploading App Previews?

Tags: app-store, osx-yosemite

I have Mavericks installed and a lot of software which I am certain will probably not all still run correctly if I upgrade to Yosemite.

My game is set for release next month and I'm looking at making an App Preview video.

I understand that Yosemite has new features that allow for *creation* of an App Preview and seamlessly pushing it to the AppStore.  I'm currently planning to use an ElGato capture device for that purpose and absolutely want to avoid upgrading to Yosemite, until I have to - especially in the middle of a release.

So given I have a video, can I just upload it using Mavericks?  The message in iTunesConnect seems to imply that you do need Yosemite (10.10), but I'm wondering if its just a poorly worded message and they are just referring to the new capture features.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question:
Yes, you really need Yosemite in order to upload your videos.  It's not about the video capture only.  With Mavericks, you can't upload videos to iTunesConnect.

Comment: Wow.  OK.  I guess its time to upgrade to Yosemite Beta - and try to deal with any issues early.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See the link for the correct answer.

https://daimtech.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/how-to-create-and-submit-a-preview-video-for-app-store-apps-using-mavericks-and-ios-8/

Comment: The link provided by @iDeveloper above essentially changes the User-Agent provided by Safari so that it pretends that it is Yosemite.  Apple really wants you to use Yosemite to upload your videos and any other solution is a back-door work-around that may stop working at some point.

Comment: So, do you need Yosemite? No... at least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a brilliant question! I am wondering myself how a company like Apple can make such bad decisions while making such a huge update!

- no developer priority buying for the new devices (we really need these devices)
- forcing 10.10 BETA UPDATE for video upload
- updating the iTunes connect page with milky instructions before having the new devices
  ....

SKRWT is my App

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a preview video without installing Yosemite. Following article contains complete steps to create and upload preview video using Mavericks OS X. [How to create and submit a preview video for App Store apps using Mavericks and iOS 8](http://daimtech.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/how-to-create-and-submit-a-preview-video-for-app-store-apps-using-mavericks-and-ios-8/)

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for this!  I guess @RawMean is still right in that Apple are still *requiring* OSX 10.10+Safari but this provides a work around.

Comment: Using this little hack with allow you to upload the video but not save it.

Comment: @o.u.m it allows to save video too!Once uploaded video is automatically saved in same way as submission graphics. Please share the issue you faced.

Comment: @FarooqNasimAhmad i'm getting this error: "Your app video preview couldn’t be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us."